# RegEx to match everything after first backslash in URL

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-4.5

I need help trying to figure out the regex to match only what is after the first backslash in a url.

URL Example:  `http://www.TestThis.com/Some-Data/Some-Other-Data/Even-More-Data`

Pattern: `^(.*?//.*?/)(.*)$`

I get 2 matches, which can work, but I really only want what is after the `http://www.TestThis.com/`

Comment: If you need to work with reasonable Urls - use Uri class (link in my answer). Otherwise please make sure to show full list of acceptable inputs and expected outputs (i.e. are `//127.0.0.1/path?fake` or `ftp://some.random.multilevel.domain.com/foo/bar.bat.bot` expected?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Uri.PathAndQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is better approach than any regEx you can come up with for valid Urls. It will also handle cases of IP instead of DNS name, % encoding used in host portion, ports and like.

```
 Console.Write(
    new Uri(
     "http://www.TestThis.com/Some-Data/Some-Other-Data/Even-More-Dat"
    ).PathAndQuery);
```

Comment: I wasn't even thinking about using that class. I seem to forget about it all the time. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You could try it without regex:

```
string test = "http://www.TestThis.com/Some-Data/Some-Other-Data/Even-More-Data";
string intermediate = test.Split(new string[] { "//" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
string final = intermediate.Substring(intermediate.IndexOf('/') + 1);
```